# SQL Joins - Gather all from RIGHT table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

`user-data`:

```
id | userID | keyID | val
1    99       1       1
```

`user-data-keys`

```
id | key           
1    is-staff
2    description
3    image
```

Now, when I run the following SQL, I get the desired output:

```
SELECT `key`,`val` FROM `user-data` RIGHT JOIN `user-data-keys` ON `user-data`.`keyID` = `user-data-keys`.`id`;
```

Which produces:

```
key         | val
is-staff      1
description   NULL
image         NULL
```

Which is exactly what I want.  However when I add a WHERE clause to the SQL:

```
SELECT `key`,`val` FROM `user-data` RIGHT JOIN `user-data-keys` ON `user-data`.`keyID` = `user-data-keys`.`id` WHERE `userID` = 99;
```

I only get the one row with `is-staff` in it.  Which I understand, as I asked for only rows with `userID = 99`.  However I am planning on storing lots of different user's information in the one `user-data` table, and I want to know if they have a NULL value for each of the keys.  So how can I achieve this?  I know it's got to be some kind of fancy join that I am not aware of.

So to clarify: i need the output like this:

```
key         | val
is-staff      1
description   NULL
image         NULL
```

When using a `WHERE userID = 99`.  Currently I only get one row whilst using a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Correct me if I am getting it wrong....are you looking for something like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp)??

Comment: @SamGhatak not really, because I want to display the `keys` field even if there is no corresponding `userID` row in `user-data`.

Comment: so you want all these rows present even after you apply a selection on them?

Comment: wat u want in output ?

Comment: dnt understand properly . can u give the desired output /

Comment: @Asad : he wants it in the format he was getting before adding the where clause

Comment: @SamGhatak That's what I thought.   But `OUTER JOIN` only returns one row again.

Comment: Ok, sorry, LEFT and RIGHT JOINs are OUTER by default in mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the predicate from the WHERE clause to the join:

```
SELECT `key`,`val` FROM `user-data` RIGHT JOIN `user-data-keys` ON `user-data`.`keyID` = `user-data-keys`.`id` and `userID` = 99;
```

Comment: it worked!! I didn't know you could add more conditionals to the the `JOIN`.  Thanks!!

Comment: Wow, missed that part completely...good catch man.. @Kane-Armstrong

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rows which are not matched then you can add where conditions with join like " ON `user-data`.`keyID` = `user-data-keys`.`id` AND `userID` = 99 " instead of " WHERE `userID` = 99 ",

```
SELECT `key`,`val` 
FROM `user-data` 
RIGHT JOIN `user-data-keys` ON `user-data`.`keyID` = `user-data-keys`.`id` AND `userID` = 99 
WHERE 1;
```